# Lambda SNS Not Printing Message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, variables, printing

I'm very new to Lambda and AWS but what I'm trying to do is make a function that checks the builder tag for certain conditions and returns a statement of action.  The code is successful in the console but and it emails the sns message, however, it is not the output I was expecting, it's just "None".  The output would be multiple lines with instances and the logic ran on them

```
import boto3  

import collections    

import datetime    

import time    

import sys

import json

import logging

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

sns = boto3.client('sns', 'us-east-1')

ec = boto3.client('ec2', 'us-east-1')    

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', 'us-east-1')    

SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn'

AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'

 

def lambda_handler(event, context):          

    instance_ids = []

    reservations = ec.describe_instances().get('Reservations', [])
    
    buildertag = [{

        "Key": "builder",

        "Value": "unknown"

    }]

   

    for reservation in reservations:

        for instance in reservation['Instances']:

            tags = {}

            for tag in instance['Tags']:

                tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']

   

            # Checks if builder tag exist and adds if it doesn't #

            if not 'builder' in tags:

                print(instance['InstanceId'] + " does not have builder tag. Adding 'builder' tag with value of 'unknown'.")

                ec.create_tags(Resources=[instance["InstanceId"]], Tags=buildertag)

     

                missingtag = print(instance['InstanceId'] + " does not have builder tag. Adding 'builder' tag with value of 'unknown'.")

                               
                sns = boto3.client('sns')

                sns.publish(

                    TopicArn = 'arn',

                    Subject = 'Incorrect Tags Dectected',

                    Message = str(missingtag),
                
                )

            # Checks for unknown tag value and print output #                                        

            elif tags['builder'] in ['Unknown', 'unknown']:

                print(instance['InstanceId'] + " has unknown for it's builder tag value.")  

                 # Checks for null tag value and print output #                                        

            elif tags['builder'] in ['']:

                print(instance['InstanceId'] + " has no value for builder tag.")  

                ec.create_tags(Resources=[instance["InstanceId"]], Tags=buildertag)

 
            # Checks for builder tags equal to approved values and print output #                                        

            elif tags['builder'] in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']:

                print(instance['InstanceId'] + " has an approved builder tag value.")  

                
 

                

            # Checks for builder tags equal to unapproved values and print output #                                        

            elif tags['builder'] not in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b']:

                print(instance['InstanceId'] + " has a incorrect builder tag value.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not returning** anything from your `lambda_handler`, thus the output is just `None`. You have to add `return` statement(s) to your code with actual return values that you want to output from the lambda.